# Progress Bar for long running scripts on shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

In my shiny app, I have a button which generates report on clicking it. Basically, it runs a script whose running time depends on the number of data files that are selected by the user. It's a single system call to the script which runs on the terminal and reports are generated in the directory. Since it's time in-determinant, is there a way to show progress in your app?

I have tried spinners which indicates loading on the screen, but a progress bar would be much better!

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/long-running-tasks-with-shiny-challenges-and-solutions/

Comment: welcome @darkshadow! Looks like this contains a working example of a progress bar:https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/progress-bar-example.html

Comment: On top of @harveyAJ good answer, you can also use `shinycssloaders` in case your code is hard to wrap in a for loop.